# XCode 14 React Native project fails to run iOS: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Trying to run the react-native project but encountered the following error

```
N/A: version "default -> N/A" is not yet installed.

You need to run "nvm install default" to install it before using it.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Output of `npx react-native info`

```
System:
    OS: macOS 12.5.1
    CPU: (10) arm64 Apple M1 Max
    Memory: 359.91 MB / 32.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.17.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.18 - ~node_modules/.bin/yarn
    npm: 8.19.1 - /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2022.09.05.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.2 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 21.4, iOS 16.0, macOS 12.3, tvOS 16.0, watchOS 9.0
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2021.2 AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683
    Xcode: 14.0/14A309 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.15 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2 
    react-native: 0.67.4 => 0.67.4 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

I did remove nvm from `./zshrc` but still got the error

Answer (score 0):

was able to resolve it by commenting out

```
# Define NVM_DIR and source the nvm.sh setup script
[ -z "$NVM_DIR" ] && export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"

# Source nvm with '--no-use' and then `nvm use` to respect .nvmrc
# See: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/2053
if [[ -s "$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh" ]]; then
  # shellcheck source=/dev/null
  . "$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh" --no-use
  nvm use 2> /dev/null || nvm use default
elif [[ -x "$(command -v brew)" && -s "$(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh" ]]; then
  # shellcheck source=/dev/null
  . "$(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh" --no-use
  nvm use 2> /dev/null || nvm use default
fi
```

in `node_modules/react-native/scripts/find-node.sh`